# JavaScript Is Text Box Empty?

Tags: javascript, html

How can I check if a input field is empty in JavaScript when submitting the form?

html:

```
<input type="text" name="start_name" id="start_name">
```

Comment: i was trying using the id. if (document.getElementById('start_name').value())  is the right?

Comment: `value` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Have your form tag as

```
<form name="myForm" action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
```

Next, have a javascript function

```
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["start_name"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("Start name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The value of a form control is always a string, so comparing to `null` will always return false.

Answer (score 0):

```
var start_name = document.getElementById('start_name');
if( start_name.value.length > 0 ){
// Then there is something there.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkme()
    {
        var inputVal = document.getElementById("start_name").value;
        if(inputVal == "")
        {
            //code
        }
    }
</script>

<form action="" method="post" onSubmit = "checkme();">
    <input type="text" name="start_name" id="start_name">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just checking 'if (x==null || x=="")' is not enough to validate empty text box. Go for RegEx to check empty text box.

```
/^\s*[0-9a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z ]*$/
```

Ensures that at least one character is not whitespace and is of one of the allowed characters.

Use `/[a-z]/i` as this regex will only match if there is at least one alphabetical character.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form action="someActionUrl" onsubmit="return validate('first_name')">
<input id="first_name" name="first_name" />
</form>

<script>
    function validate(inputId){
        var val = document.getElementById(inputId).value;

        if(val.length>0){
          // do something
           return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:
    var x = document.getElementById("start_name");
    if(x.value== "")
    {
     //your restriction code comes here
    }
    else
    {
     //go ahead!
    }

Note: please check for syntax if its proper.i am writing the code here directly,haven't checked  it on IDE.